# trying to create a proc ( delete items from inv )

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

well iam trying to create a proc have the ability to delete item from my inv game
but i keep fail at it ^^
seems my query not right or missing something

```
USE [OVERLIMIT_SHARD_NOW]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[_Remove_Items_From_Inv]    Script Date: 03/31/2013 04:18:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_Remove_Items_From_Inv] /* by Me */

    @CharID INT

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @ID64 INT ;

 (SELECT RefItemID FROM [DataBaseName].[dbo].[_Items] with(NOLOCK) WHERE ID64 = @ID64)

    BEGIN
        UPDATE _Inventory SET ItemID = 0 WHERE ItemID  IN ( SELECT ID64 FROM _Items WHERE RefItemID in ( 46440 , 46441 , 46442 ) and CharID = @CharID )
    END

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Comment: One observation: You declare `@ID64`, but don't assign it a value before you use it (`WHERE ID64 = @ID64`).  The result is `@ID64` is NULL, so when it is used, the where clause is evaluated as `WHERE ID64 = NULL`.

Comment: hmm didn't understand you xD

Comment: Not sure how to better explain it...  `declare @ID64 INT` is the same as `declare @ID64 INT = NULL`.  If you don't assign something to `@ID64` before you use it, then it is still going to be a `NULL` when you use it.  Why are you using it in the `SELECT ... WHERE ID64 = @ID64`?  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?